# Creating a curved rectangle on outside of a sphere?

Tags: modeling

I'm having trouble finding a way to create a rectangular mesh that sits on the outside of a sphere (but takes the shape of the sphere).

Can someone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: can you add an image of what you want to achieve ?

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://puu.sh/5QEtZ.png Or this? http://puu.sh/5QEzT.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do something like this:
[image]

To model that:

1. Add a plane (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > Add > Mesh > Plane).
2. Give it some extra geometry with a Simple Subdivision surface modifier:
   [image]
3. Add a shrink wrap modifier and select the target object in the Target input box:

   [image]
4. Add a Solidify modifier to give it some thickness:

   [image]

And you get:

[image]

Comment: Seems like an unnecessary lot of work if the plane is going to take on the shape/curvature of the sphere. Why not just duplicate a part of the sphere, extrude and separate.

Comment: @iKlsR, this technique is more flexible and allows you to position the plane wherever you want on the sphere.

Comment: I agree with @iKlsR, because you can still position the plane as you wish, if you set the plane's center the same as the sphere's center, then use Rotate tool.

Comment: @Polosson, good point, but you can't shift it to a non centered position. i.e. http://puu.sh/5QMYc.png

Even so, there are multiple ways to do it. iKlsR or Polosson, could you post an answer outlining the other technique?

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for.  Cheers!