# How project/Cut a path over sphere

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I found one tutorial of software PTC Creo 2.0 to try to do the same in Blender, I imported the path from Illustrator like .svg file, place in the zone to project, but when use shrikwrap modifier, nothing happen or deform the path. I post the images of the my process and the tutorial like reference. I reading this link: [Some similar question like this...](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5652/creating-a-curved-rectangle-on-outside-of-a-sphere) but is a rectangle and my path are irregular form and don´t have the same project form like tutorial.

[image: the all in position...]

[image: the modifier shrinkwrap applied nothing happen...]

[image: images from the tutorial for software PTC Creo 2.0]

[image: images from the tutorial for software PTC Creo 2.0]

[image: images from the tutorial for software PTC Creo 2.0]

[image: images from the tutorial for software PTC Creo 2.0]

[image: The uses of the part..]

[My model before apply modifier...](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rnkrcqh760wj93g/exercise1.blend)

[image: capture of modifier stack]

Comment: Could you upload your .blend or add some screenshots of your modifier stack?

Comment: @gandalf3 I added my model .blend and one capture when aplied the modifier, check how the lines convert, don´t project anything... thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like "Knife Project" should do exactly what you want to do [(described in the manual)](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Knife_Subdivide)

Also, the manual doesn't mention that the projection originates from your point of view. I kept trying to use the tool while "looking" at the objects from the side, and nothing happened. Then [this thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?319052-Knife-Project-tool) wisened me up.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your shrinkwrap modifier is not doing what you expect it to is because it is rotate 90 degrees around the X axis.

The shrinkwrap projection axes seem to use local coordinates, so with the 90 degree rotation the -Z is pointing the same direction as the global +Y.

E.g.:

[image]

Keep in mind that the shrinkwrap modifier only affects the CV points when used on curves (not the generated geometry).

If you want to affect the geometry, you must convert the curve to a mesh (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>)